# Stop all scripts in a page from loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

I've been trying to get this code working in Google Chrome but I can't seem to be able to stop server requests from "removed" scripts from happening.

What I'm trying to do is remove all scripts in a page, the code below removes the scripts from the DOM but they still load and execute.

Code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var e2 = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for(var i = e2.length; i--; e2[i].parentNode.removeChild(e2[i]));
});​
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scripts are blocking, so any script tag that appears before the closing body tag is downloaded, parsed and executed before the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

You could always take a look at async or defer attributes on your script tags, but you'd still be guessing if they have been executed or not by the time your `DOMContentLoaded` listeners gets executed.

You should really try to look for an alternative method to achieve what you want to accomplish here. Might I ask what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for answering, it's a tampermonkey script (personal use) to auto sign-in on a website with some cookie issues. I'm trying to get the sign-in as near instantaneous as possible so I'd like to remove all images, stylesheets and scripts. It's a small issue for me but I figured it's something that would be used by a lot of people and an answer should be available somewhere on the internet.

Comment: An answer is available - right here, bad idea (I'll always hesitate to say anything is impossible) to try and make a lightweight page this way. The good news is if you stick your auto-sign in script in the header and just let it execute, it will probably execute and auto-sign in before most everything else on the page is downloaded. Alternatively, is there a method you can check server side to determine if the user is going to be auto-signing in? If that's the case, then just serve them up a lightweight page, or better yet, don't serve them anything and just auto log them in.

Comment: True... but wouldn't I have to ditch Tampermonkey then? And isn't one of the "features" of Chrome that an extension can't delay or prevent a page load?